# Salen varias veces las ventanas de JOptionPane

Tags: java, joptionpane

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Perdón si no me expliqué, adjunto algunas fotos para que sea más entendible.
En sí estoy realizando un interfaz, y puse un botón de Aceptar, que lo programé para que me diera una respuesta de "Has asignado tus materias" si la persona realizaba alguna selección en la interfaz, pero si no realizaba ninguna me diera el mensaje de "Es necesario seleccionar una opción", esto con JOptionPane, hasta eso todo bien, el problema es que al darle click al botón me salta el mensaje según lo que seleccione, pero si le vuelvo a dar otra vez click al botón me lanza 2 veces el mensaje en el JOption, y si le vuelvo a picar al botón ahora me lo muestra 3 veces, asi consecutivamente. EN SI está como en un bucle. Este es mi código.

```
 btn_aceptar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    private String checkbox;
    boolean selected = false;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (box_calculo.isSelected()) {
            box_calculo.setEnabled(false);
            selected = true;
        }
        if (box_probabilidad.isSelected()) {
            box_probabilidad.setEnabled(false);
            selected = true;
        }
        if (box_arquitectura.isSelected()) {
            box_arquitectura.setEnabled(false);
            selected = true;
        }                
        if (box_mecanica.isSelected()) {
            box_mecanica.setEnabled(false);
            selected = true;
        }                
        if (box_estructura.isSelected()) {
            box_estructura.setEnabled(false);
            selected = true;
        }                
        if (box_fundamentos.isSelected()) {
            box_fundamentos.setEnabled(false);
            selected = true;
        }                
        if (box_etica.isSelected()) {
            box_etica.setEnabled(false);
            selected = true;       
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Aun estás cursando un cuatrimestre");
        }
        if (!selected) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debes seleccionar al menos una opción.");
        }
    }
 });
```

Comment: Al parecer con cada click le estás agregando un "new ActionListener()", deberías ver la forma de "limpiar" los listener para que no se vayan acumulando. Revisa si existe algún método que te permita eliminar los listeners tal vez algo llamado ".removeActionListener" o similar si es que existe.

Comment: Hola Antonio, bienvenido, podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar el resto del método?, gracias.

Comment: ¿Donde esta este código? ¿No estará dentro de un ciclo? Indica mas código que no termina de quedar claro por favor.